# CrawlSpider with Splash

Tags: python, scrapy, slash

I have some problem with my spider. I use splash with scrapy to get link to "Next page" which is generate by JavaScript. After downloading the information from the first page, I want to download information from the following pages, but LinkExtractor function does not work properly. But it looks like start_request function doesn't work. Here is code:

```
class ReutersBusinessSpider(CrawlSpider):
   name = 'reuters_business'
   allowed_domains = ["reuters.com"]
   start_urls = (
       'http://reuters.com/news/archive/businessNews?view=page&page=1',
   )

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 0.5}
                }
            })
    def use_splash(self, request):
        request.meta['splash'] = {
                'endpoint':'render.html',
                'args':{
                    'wait':0.5,
                    }
                }
        return request

    def process_value(value):
        m = re.search(r'(\?view=page&page=[0-9]&pageSize=10)', value)
        if m:
            return urlparse.urljoin('http://reuters.com/news/archive/businessNews',m.group(1))


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@class="pageNext"]',process_value='process_value'),process_request='use_splash', follow=False),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h2/*[contains(@href,"article")]',process_value='process_value'),callback='parse_item'),
    )



    def parse_item(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=PajaczekItem(), response=response)

        l.add_xpath('articlesection','//span[@class="article-section"]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip), Join())
        l.add_xpath('date','//span[@class="timestamp"]/text()', MapCompose(parse))
        l.add_value('url',response.url)
        l.add_xpath('articleheadline','//h1[@class="article-headline"]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.title))
        l.add_xpath('articlelocation','//span[@class="location"]/text()')
        l.add_xpath('articletext','//span[@id="articleText"]//p//text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip), Join())

        return l.load_item()
```

Logs:

```
2016-02-12 08:20:29 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened 2016-02-12 08:20:29 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-02-12 08:20:29 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-02-12 08:20:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST localhost:8050/render.html>; (referer: None)
2016-02-12 08:20:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'localhost': <GET http://localhost:8050/render.html?page=2&pageSize=10&view=page%3E;
2016-02-12 08:20:38 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Where is mistake? Thanks for help.

Comment: *"but LinkExtractor function does not work properly. But it looks like start_request function doesn't work."* What are you seeing? what do you expect instead? can you share your logs?

Comment: 2016-02-12 08:20:29 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
   2016-02-12 08:20:29 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
   2016-02-12 08:20:29 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
   2016-02-12 08:20:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
   2016-02-12 08:20:38 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'localhost': <GET http://localhost:8050/render.html?page=2&pageSize=10&view=page>
   2016-02-12 08:20:38 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Comment: The answer already provided is probably the main reason things do not work. But I’ve also noticed that you are passing callbacks to the LinkExtractor class as a string. You should find some examples of LinkExtractor usage to understand how callbacks are specified (e.g. `self.process_value`, not `'process_value'`).

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance, you're not calling your start_request property using splash...  For example,   you should be using SplashRequest.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplahRequest(url, self.parse, meta={
            'splash': {
                'endpoint': 'render.html',
                'args': {'wait': 0.5}
            }
        })
```

Giving that you have Splash set up appropriate,  that is in settings you have enabled the necessary middle where's and pointed to the correct /url also enabled them to fire and HTTP cache  all correctly...  No I have not run your code should be good to go now

## EDIT: BTW... its not next page is not js generated

[image: Next Page not JS generater]

So... unless there is any other reason your using splash I see no reason to use it  a simple for loop in the initial parsing of the articles request like...

```
for next in response.css("a.control-nav-next::attr(href)").extract():
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next), callback=self.parse...
```